# Visual Basic , code Cleaner

Tags: vb.net, path, folderbrowserdialog

I am making a directory cleaner that uses the following code

```
Label2.Text = "Cleaned."
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\*.txt")
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\*.jpg")
    End If
    If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\*.v3d")
    End If
    If CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\*.bin")
    End If
    If CheckBox5.Checked = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\*.dmp")
    End If
    If CheckBox6.Checked = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\*.dump")
    End If
    If CheckBox7.Checked = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        System.IO.File.SetAttributes("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\EndingBanner.exe", System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
        Kill("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\EndingBanner.exe")
    End If
    If CheckBox8.Checked = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        System.IO.File.SetAttributes("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\CAV.exe", System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
        Kill("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\CAV.exe")
    End If
    If CheckBox9.Checked = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        If Dir("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\MOVIES") <> "" Then
            Rename("C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\Game\MOVIES", "C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\Game\CLEANED")
        End If
    End If
```

But instead of stating the directory in the program I want the user to select it , "C:\Nexon\Combat Arms\" using SelectDirectory; I have this but, cant make it work

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim MyFolderBrowser As New System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    Dim dlgResult As DialogResult = MyFolderBrowser.ShowDialog()

    Me.FileReference.Text = MyFolderBrowser.SelectedPath


End Sub
```

Comment: "can't make it work" doesn't tell us anything.  What have you tried, and what unexpected behaviour are you observing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folderbrowser code works fine. Are you having a problem implementing this?

```
Kill(Me.FileReference.Text & "\*.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a message box to display the selected path. See if is giving you what you want. If this isn't working try another property like selected directory or sorts. I don't have VS open right now to look myself but what you have should work as long as selected path is right. I have a feeling that if you got the selected path if that is what you want and assign it to a string variable first, it might work. Could be a formatting problem with the path. Just try the message box first to see if the path is right.